# Running orchardcms from webmatrix first time throws jQuery error

Tags: orchardcms

I am running orchardCMS from webmatrix. On first run it should ideally show me set up page. But it is showing error - "A 'script' named 'jQuery' could not be found".

How to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: What version of Orchard did you download (please provide the exact link)?

Comment: This is the link shown when Orchard is installed from webplatform installer https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/releases/download/1.10.1/Orchard.Web.zip

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not compiling from source?

Comment: I am validating use of orchard. I thought of using out of box application to have a look. Now I have went through source code and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to compile Orchard from source: the web platform installer is mostly there for hosting platforms to provide a ready-built option to their customers. If you are going to do any customization, source is best.